# How do I delete employees at a time who worked more than 5 years

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sql-delete

I have a code that deletes a specific employee if he/she worked for more than 5 years. I want to apply this statement to all employees at one time.

```
DECLARE 
  currentDate DATE := SYSDATE;
  hireDate Date;
  empId number := 100;
BEGIN
    
    SELECT hire_date INTO hireDate FROM employees
    WHERE employee_id = empId;
    
        DELETE FROM emp
        WHERE (currentDate-hireDate) / 365 > 5 AND employee_id = empId;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQL%ROWCOUNT || ' rows deleted.');
END;
```

As you can see that I declared empId as 100. `currentDate-hireDate / 365 > 5` of this employee returns 4, which is false. I have 107 employees at my table, starting from 100 till 206. If I delete `WHERE employee_id = empId;` , it returns too many rows error. What could you recommend me about this?

Comment: What errors are you getting when removing the employee_id = empId clause?

Comment: THe errors too many rows suggest that the empid column isnt unique in your table emp

Comment: The right way would be to use a SQL query and no the PL/SQL way of coding

Comment: DELETE FROM emp
        WHERE (sysdate-hireDate) / 365 > 5;

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph there are some issues with this statement ; (1) pseudocolumn `sysdate` has time portion, (2) division by `365` might yield wrong results due to leap year(s)

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead.

```
 DATEDIFF(dd,hireDate,currentDate)/365.0
```

Comment: but there's no such predefined function exists in Oracle DB.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MONTHS_BETWEEN()` function along with `TRUNC()` without need of `PL/SQL` such as

```
DELETE emp 
 WHERE TRUNC( MONTHS_BETWEEN( current_date, hire_date ) / 12 ) >= 5
   AND employee_id = 100
```

along with including the *exact 5 year* difference, but I recommend you rather use a soft delete such as

```
UPDATE emp
   SET active = 0 
 WHERE TRUNC( MONTHS_BETWEEN( current_date, hire_date ) / 12 ) >= 5
   AND employee_id = 100
   AND active = 1
```

If you still want to use PL/SQL, then use the following code

```
DECLARE 
  empId   emp.employee_id%type := 100;
BEGIN
  UPDATE emp
     SET active = 0 
   WHERE TRUNC( MONTHS_BETWEEN( current_date, hire_date ) / 12 ) >= 5
     AND employee_id = 100
     AND active = 1;
     
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQL%ROWCOUNT || ' rows deleted.');
END;
/
```

where the local variables `currentDate`(use `current_date` function instead), `hireDate` and the `SELECT` statement are redundant within the current case.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=97195cbd1101c69d97280bc705b6b152)</kbd>